# make a test python options mandatory

Tags: python

I am using getopt to get the options from command line. How can I check if an option has been set or not. I have tried by setting a value to 1 and test it and it works but I was wondering if there is another way to do it?

```
def main(argv):
    inputfile = ''
    outputfile = ''
    i = 0
    o = 0
    d = 0
    usage = """
Usage:  rotate.py [OPTIONS] ...
    rotate.py -i img1.jpg -o img2.py -d 10
    rotate.py -i img1.jpg -d 10

    -h --help               Display this usage message
    -i --ifile <inputfile>          The file to rotate
    -o --ofile <outputfile>         The file that will have the rotated image.
    -d --degres <integer>           The number of degres to rotate
"""
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:d:",["ifile=","ofile=","degres=","help"])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print usage
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            print usage
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            inputfile = arg
            i = 1
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            outputfile = arg
            o = 1
        elif opt in ("-d", "--degres"):
            degres = arg
            d = 1
    if (inputfile in globals()) & (outputfile in globals()) & (degres in globals()):
        rotate_picture(inputfile, outputfile, degres)
    elif (inputfile in globals()) & (degres in globals()):
        rotate_picture(inputfile, inputfile, degres)
    else:
        print usage

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Is it too late to point out that [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) (part of Python since 2.7) supports parsing mandatory arguments and is easier to use?

Comment: From the `getopt` docs: " Users who are unfamiliar with the C getopt() function *or who would like to write less code and get better help and error messages should consider using the argparse module instead*." Trust me, you will thank yourself for switching to `argparse`.

Comment: I ve gone through argparse and you are right, it is so much better :). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd set the arguments to `None` beforehand, then test if they are *still* `None` after parsing:

```
inputfile = outputfile = degres = None

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
        print usage
        sys.exit()
    elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
        inputfile = arg
        i = 1
    elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
        outputfile = arg
        o = 1
    elif opt in ("-d", "--degres"):
        degres = arg
        d = 1

if inputfile is None or degres is None:
    print usage
    sys.exit(1)

outputfile = outputfile or inputfile

rotate_picture(inputfile, outputfile, degres)
```

Note that you use `and` and `or` in Python to do boolean tests, `&` is a *bitwise* AND operator; it combines the bits of integers into new integers.

An argparse version would be:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Rotate an image')
parser.add_argument('inputfile', type=argparse.FileType('r+b'),
                    help='The file to rotate')
parser.add_argument('degrees', type=int,
                    help='The number of degrees to rotate')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', type=argparse.FileType('wb'),
                    help='The file to write the result to. Defaults to the inputfile')

args = parser.parse_args()
outputfile = args.output or args.inputfile
rotate_picture(args.inputfile, outputfile, args.degrees)
```

and the help is auto-generated for you as:

```
usage: [-h] [-o OUTPUT] inputfile degrees

Rotate an image

positional arguments:
  inputfile             The file to rotate
  degrees               The number of degrees to rotate

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT
                        The file to write the result to. Defaults to the
                        inputfile
```